# Console App with Hosting APIs just STOPS after certain command on VPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, ubuntu, vps, discord.net

I have a Discord bot with this command.

```cs
[Command("synopses", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
[Summary("Shows current synopses.")]
public async Task Synopses(string username)
{
    var warning = await ReplyAsync($"{Context.User.Mention} I am querying the Tracker, this may take a moment.");
    var synopses = await _trackerService.GetUserSynopses(username);
    var pager = BuildSynopsesPager(synopses);
    await warning.DeleteAsync();
    await PagedReplyAsync(pager, new ReactionList());
}
```

The `_trackerService.GetUserSynopses(username);` is a very long Task, takes about 10 seconds.

```cs
public async Task<List<Synopsis>> GetUserSynopses(string username)
{
    var synopses = new List<Synopsis>();
 
    // This request to the Google Sheets API is the bulk of the time.
    // It gets about 4k rows.
    var tracker = await GetTrackerAsync();

    foreach (var sheet in tracker.Sheets)
    {
        var data = sheet.Data;
        
        var writes = data
            .Select(x => x.RowData)
            .First()
            .Where(x => x.Values.Count >= 11)
            .Where(x => x.Values[3].FormattedValue == username);
        
        static bool ParseFinal(string text)
        {
            return text switch
            {
                "Yes" => true,
                _ => false
            };
        }
    
        var result = writes
            .Select(write => write.Values)
            .Select(cells => new Synopsis
            {
                DateClaimed = cells[0].FormattedValue,
                SeriesTitle = cells[1].FormattedValue,
                SeriesHyperlink = cells[1].Hyperlink ?? "No Hyperlink",
                ClaimType = Enum.Parse<ClaimType>(cells[2].FormattedValue),
                Claimant = cells[3].FormattedValue,
                Document = cells[4].Hyperlink ?? "No Hyperlink",
                Final = ParseFinal(cells[5].FormattedValue)
            });
    
        synopses.AddRange(result);
    }
    
    return synopses;
}
```

```cs
public async Task<Spreadsheet> GetTrackerAsync()
{
    await using var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    var credential = GoogleCredential
        .FromStream(stream)
        .CreateScoped();

    var sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Hiromi"
    });
    
    const string spreadsheetId = "1wbIqigHMGFWZebum8mQjSL5eQzSAXuWZS-8ewbFX4PI";

    var request = sheetsService
        .Spreadsheets
        .Get(spreadsheetId);

    request.IncludeGridData = true;
    request.Ranges = new[] {"'Synopses In Progress'!A3:K", "'Archive'!A2:L"};

    return await request.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

So when I run this command while my application is running locally from my IDE, it works fine no matter how many times I execute. But when my application is running from my VPS, it works the first time, but the second time it executes `var warning = await ReplyAsync($"{Context.User.Mention} I am querying the Tracker, this may take a moment.");` and then hangs for a while, and then literally stops.

As you can see

```
[09:41:13 DBG] Foreign key property 'Message.Id' detected as changed. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see property values.
[09:41:13 DBG] A data reader was disposed.
[09:41:13 DBG] Committing transaction.
[09:41:13 DBG] Committing transaction.
[09:41:13 DBG] Closing connection to database 'hiromi' on server 'tcp://149.28.226.90:5432'.
[09:41:13 DBG] Closed connection to database 'hiromi' on server 'tcp://149.28.226.90:5432'.
[09:41:13 DBG] Disposing transaction.
[09:41:13 DBG] An 'Message' entity tracked by 'HiromiContext' changed from 'Added' to 'Unchanged'. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see key values.
[09:41:13 DBG] SaveChanges completed for 'HiromiContext' with 1 entities written to the database.
root@Hamsterland:~/Bots/Hiromi/Hiromi.Bot#
```

The process terminated at the end but not because I terminated it; it terminated automatically after a few seconds.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: if the application crashes, then most likely there is an error, if you currently aren't logging one then you probably have some gaps in your logging. A quick work around would be to wrap the suspected code in a try/catch and log whatever exception is caught. Once you know what's wrong you can remove the try/catch and either code to prevent the error or gracefully handle it.

Comment: @Anu6is put the command in a try catch, nothing is caught. Still hangs and terminates. No error in the command executed event either.